# Pass data to Angular UI Router not changing when state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to pass different data to each state while using angular-ui-router. Though am able to pass data, its not changing when the route change. For example see code below:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


    $stateProvider

        // route to show main page with satisfied/unsatisfied
        .state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            templateUrl: 'container.html',
            controller: 'formController',

        })

        .state('main.happy', {
            url: '/happy',
            data: {  happy: true },  
            templateUrl: 'happy.html',

        })

        .state('main.sad', {
            url: '/sad',
            data: {  happy: false },  
            templateUrl: 'welcome.html'
        })


    // catch all route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');


})
```

In the above code when I goto path `/happy`, I can see the data is being taken, but when I goto the path `/sad` the data is not changing. While the value of happy have to false in the case of path `/sad` its still remains otherwise. It's only when I refresh the data is changing. Which defeats the whole purpose by I am using Angular.

Comment: Where/how are you accessing the value of `data`?

Comment: When the data is passed to the back-end, I am passing this info too. In sad and happy, both the paths there is a form. And this form when submitted, this value is also submitted to the backend. Am adding it to the `formData` like this `$scope.formData.happy= happy;`. So this is basically serving the purpose of default values set in a hidden input or something.

Comment: Try injecting `$state` via DI and using `$scope.formData.happy= $state.current.data.happy;`

Comment: I have just started understanding Angular Js, to be honest I am not very clear on what you suggest here. But is it the below code when you say DI?

`.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $state) {`

If so, will the route code be like this:
 `.state('main.sad', {
            url: '/sad',
            data: {  happy: false },  
            templateUrl: 'welcome.html'
        })`
And then I get it in controller like this:
`$scope.formData.happy= $state.current.data.happy;`

Comment: in the same place you inject `$scope`, something like `.controller('...',function($scope, $state){...});`

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do something like this:

```
.state('main', {
    url: '/main/:mood',
    templateUrl: 'container.html',
    controller: 'formController',
})

mainApp.controller('formController', function($state) {
    console.log($state.params.mood); // -> happy
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in that way because you use here child states (`main.happy` and `main.sad`).

When you move between child states, ui-router doesn't create new instance of your parent controller (in your case `formController`). If you want you can add simple `console.log` in `formController` and look that message will be displayed only once.

All what you have to do is create new instance of formController everytime when you go to a state.

If you want refresh your child/parent view, you can do it directly by using `$state` service and pass options object with parameter reload equals to true.

```
$state.go('main.happy', null, {reload: true});
```

or use `ui-sref-opts` directive somewhere in your view, like:

```
<a ui-sref="main.happy" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Go to happy state</a>
```

I created also plunker for you with working demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/GxNLWsvlLotRRNdjUxFr?p=preview